# Create Inclusions and exclusions

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I am creating a plugin for booking tour packages. I have created custom post type `packages` and some meta data for that, now I want to create inclusion and exclusion list with icons and show all this with checkbox while adding new package. How can I do that? Is there any plugin available to perform this?

Comment: I dont know if youve considered it but, You can use the WordPress metabox to add fields to your custom post type

Comment: The contributed answers in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/ contain details on how to do this